# Simple Circuit Analysis Question

Tags: resistors

My son had this particular problem on a Electrical Systems test and had difficulty with it. I am stumped myself. The task is to find the resistance values of each resistor, the current through each resistor, and the voltage across each resistor. The schematic is shown with a given 8 mA of current through R1 and R2 and 28 V across R4.
[image]

Comment: More information is needed to come up with a unique answer. Otherwise, choose a battery voltage >= 28V, solve for resistance ratios, and give arbitrary values to two of the resistors. Is this supposed to be a balanced bridge where the voltages across R2 = R4?

Comment: The question must have had more information. For example, "All resistors are equal." With this simple assumption the problem is easily solved.

Comment: This is all the information that was given, unfortunately.   The schematic is all that was given.  I too thought something else has to be given to solve this.

Comment: All you can say is that \$R_1+R_2=3.5\:\text{k}\Omega\left(1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}\right)\$.

Comment: I suggest you also post the exact question as it is written. There must definitely be some other assumption or information. Otherwise the problem is intractable

Comment: There is some conditions. Vcc must be >= 28 V. (R1+R2)=Vcc/8 mA. And then, r4/(r3+r4)*Vcc=28. Double infinity of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by inspection you can see that the problem is insoluble.

For instance, R1 and R2 are in series, but without being given any information about what is happening at their mid point, even if you could work out their total series value, you could not determine their ratio.

You have 5 unknowns, four resistor values and a battery voltage.

You have two knowns, a resistor voltage and a resistor current.

You need another three equations to be able to solve it completely.

As it happens, an assumption of all resistors equal would give you another three equations, R2=R1, R3=R1 etc, and an easy solution. But they don't have to be equal. Any three resistor ratios, or other voltages or current measures in the circuit, would give you the extra required three equations.

... As long as they are independent equations. Being told R1's current and R2's current does not count as two equations.

Given the R3/4 ratio, you get the battery voltage, which then gives you the R1+R2 series resistance value. Knowing the R1/R2 ratio gievs you those two uniquely. Then knowing a ratio between any resistor in the left branch, and any in the right branch, gives you the R3 and R4 values.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the substitution theorem, the given network can be modified in the following way where the unknowns are two: Vcc and R3:

[image]
It seems unsolvable:
[image]

Comment: This makes sense.  Could you take the problem to completion?

Comment: There is not enough information to solve it.